# Button by createElement() in JavaScript's Web Component not Showing

Tags: javascript, web-component

I am creating a vanilla js component for button, The problem is when I call the component class in my another page It is not showing button but only my-button tag

when I console the button or button.innerHtml it shows desire result

```html
<html>
<head><script src="button/j-button.js"></script></head>
<body>    
<j-button></j-button>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
window.customElements.define('j-button',
    class jButton extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.templating();
        }
        templating(){
            var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            button.innerHTML="my button";
        }
    });
```

my button should appear with content "my button"

Answer (score 2):

Append the button to the custom element. All you have done is create it in memory

```js
window.customElements.define('j-button',
    class jButton extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.templating();
        }
        templating(){
            var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            button.innerHTML="my button";
            // append button to the custom element
            this.appendChild(button);
        }
    });
```

```html
<j-button></j-button>
```

Comment: You should not modify children in a constructor. By calling `this.templating()` you are adding a child while still in the constructor. https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-element-conformance